# Why $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5)$?

Tags: galois-theory

I'm trying to show that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 5)/\mathbb Q$ is an extension of degree 4. I know how to prove that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 5)/\mathbb Q$ has degree $4$, and now I want to find an isomorphism between $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 5)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5)$, but didn't work... How can I proceed ?

Comment: You seem to be muddling $\sqrt 3$ and $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @lulu : I don't know this case (I just started with galois theory), but I can imagine it's the same

Answer (score 6):

No isomorphism is needed :

$$(\sqrt 2-\sqrt 5)(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 5)=-3,$$
i.e. $\sqrt 2-\sqrt 5\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 5)$
and

$$\sqrt 2=\frac{\sqrt 2+\sqrt 5+(\sqrt 2-\sqrt 5)}{2},$$
$$\sqrt 5=\frac{\sqrt 2+\sqrt 5-(\sqrt 2-\sqrt 5)}{2}.$$

Comment: Is there an other way ? (this way looks very tricky)...

Comment: This question has been asked many times. A general solution can be found here  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2457638/300700