# If $E= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{7})$ Show that $E/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois Extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, splitting-field, galois-extensions

If $E= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{7})$ Show that $E/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois Extension.

I know that $E/Q$ must be a normal and separable extension.

I can also show that

(1) E is a splitting field of a separable polynomial with coefficients in F.

(2) Every irreducible polynomial in F[x] with at least one root in E splits over E and is separable.

How can I determine which approach will be better, or there is another approach to solve this?. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to worry about separable. In characteristic $0$ it comes automatically.

Comment: Hint -  Can you identify quadratic subfields? Is the compositum of normal extensions normal?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Notice that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{7})=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{7})$ which is the splitting field of:

> $(x^2-2)(x^2-7)$

So, I guess in this case the way that you see this is by finding a polynomial of which your extension field is the splitting field by using the adjoined roots.

Comment: Once you know that $Q(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 7)=Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 7)$, you can conclude because te compositum of two Galois extensions is Galois. Your question (and the answer) can be generalized: $Q(\sqrt a + \sqrt b)=Q(\sqrt a, \sqrt b)$ **always**. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2457638/300700